# How to store value into a generic class field (Mono.Cecil)

Tags: c#, generics, il, mono.cecil

I'm using Mono.Cecil for rewriting some assemblies. Given a generic class with a string field for example. I want to generate code into a method of this class which writes into this field.
This is the code to achieve that:

```
var origInstanceField = type.Fields.First(fld => fld.Name.Equals("_original"));
InsertBeforeReturn(instanceMethod.Body, new[]
{
   Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
   Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "genCodeToOriginal"),
   Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Stfld, origInstanceField)
});
```

For non-generic classes it works like a charm. For generic classes it creates bad IL. If you take a look on the decompiled IL you can spot the difference compared to the same instructions emitted by the compiler.

```
.method public hidebysig instance void FillFields() cil managed
{
.maxstack 8
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldarg.0 
L_0002: ldstr "non-gen code to non-gen field"
L_0007: stfld string TestConsole.GenericClass`1<!T>::_original
L_0017: ldarg.0 
L_0018: ldstr "genCodeToOriginal"
L_001d: stfld string TestConsole.GenericClass`1::_original
L_0022: ret 
}
```

The field reference points to the open generic type [GenericClass<>] and not to the to be constructed type [GenericClass< T>].
I tried also with a static field with the same result.
Any idea how can I get to the right FieldDefinition?

Comment: Why are you not just using reflection?

Comment: What is `type`? It can't be the `TypeBuilder`, since that doesn't have a `Fields` property.

Comment: Reflection could be fine, but in my case I'll also create the field with Cecil, so no reflection. Variable type is a TypeDefinition.

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to find a solution by looking at the source code of Anotar (https://github.com/Fody/Anotar). The trick is to create a field reference with a type definition refering to an instantiated generic, not the original one.

```
var declaringType = new GenericInstanceType(definition.DeclaringType);
foreach (var parameter in definition.DeclaringType.GenericParameters)
{
     declaringType.GenericArguments.Add(parameter);
}
return new FieldReference(definition.Name, definition.FieldType, declaringType);
```

Using this transformation on the FieldDefinition coming from type gives the right FieldReference. Feeding the generic parameters to generic arguments is a little odd but makes sense.